# Can anything be assumed from the use of "Jungfrau" in an old German marriage record?

Tags: germany, marriage-records, german-language

For the Braunschweig family, I have been able to find record of and to connect every person in the Creuzburg, Germany area of the 1600s.  There were two Elisabetha Braunschweigs alive and unmarried in the years 1667 to 1671.  (I have two different known connections to this family.)

- Elisabetha Cattharina Braunschweig, born to Gorge Lintohe Braunschweig and Cattarina Rassian in 1648 (Liz#1)
- Elisabetha Braunschweig, born to Jeremias Braunschweig and Margaratha Buffan in 1650 (Liz#2)

For the Burkhardt family, which I am still working on researching during that same timeframe, there was happily only one Nicolaus Burkhardt.  (I have one known connection to the Burkhardt family.)

Due to how far back this is, the only available records are baptism, marriage, and death.  Death records only record the husband's surname, no "daughter of", age at death, or anything else useful.  So the only available hint is the marriage record.

Marriage record of a jungfrau Elisabetha Braunschweig in 1667:
(Liz#1 would have been 17, Liz#2 would have been 19)

[image]

Marriage record of an Elisabetha Braunschweig in 1671:
(Liz#1 would have been 21, Liz#2 would have been 23)

[image]

So it's safe to say that my Burkhardt and Braunschweig lines converged...  but which part of the Braunschweig line?  The only difference here I can see is the 'jungfrau'.  I know it means virgin or maiden, but is there any rhyme or reason why it would or would not have been used for a particular case, or is there anything else here that might help hint at which Elisabetha married Nicolaus?

Comment: "Jungfrau" meant that the bride was never married before (and of a young age, mainly between 18 to 22 usually) and that the indicated marriage is the first one, unlike those who remarry after their husband's death would be called "Wittbe" for widow. They would be usually between 25 to 40 years of age.

Comment: Are both records from the same parish? 'Usually' if there's the possibly of confusion (at the time of the event), there will be something to differentiate (eg father's name). If different locations, that would be the distinguishing datum. (BTW the ages of Liz#1 & #2 seem reversed).

Comment: Does either of the couples have children? Sometimes the baptization records contain some helpful bits about the parents. If the godparents are given, they could also provide hints.

Comment: Came here to say the same as jadepx.

Comment: bgwiehle, yes, both records are from the same town.

Comment: Some death certificates include the parents (and sometimes husband/wife). You might get lucky and find the right connection by finding the death certificate. Also closely look at the childrens documents to see if there is any document that contains the middle name. Catharina is a common name, so that may not be enough to completely rule out the other Elisabetha (since maybe you are missing a middle name here), but it would be a strong hint towards one of the two.